# XNA rotation not working correctly

Tags: xna, rotation

So, I'm trying to rotate 5 vectors2s to get target(Vector2) as a normal for them. But when I rotate it isn't rotating properly. When target is pointing up and verticies' normal right or left(default: 0,-1 0,0 0,1) I have to rotate them 90 degrees but when I do result isn't -1,0 0,0 1,0 what it should be. Instead it is something like: -1,vs 0,0 1,-vs vs=very small number. Why is this? Is there a way to correct this? Code:

```
Vector2 target = new Vector2(0, 1); //Create target

Vector2[] vecs = new Vector2[3] { new Vector2(0, -1), Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(0, 1) }; //Create verticies to be rotated

Matrix matrix = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(90)); //Should be: (float)Math.Atan2(target.Y, target.X) instead of 90 but wanted to simplify this

Vector2.Transform(vecs, ref matrix, vecs); // Rotate
```

I even tried rotating with 360 degrees for full turn but that didn't give me the starting vectors, which is weird to me.

Comment: when working with floats a value within 0.0000001 of expected results is 99.99999 % of the time good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is this?

Its because of the precision of floating point variables.

### Is there a way to correct this?

I dont know a way, but I would just ignore it. Because it is nearly equal to zero.

### Protip

With the given vector (x,y), (-y,x) or (y,-x) are the normals of this vector.